# Tab Bar Controller with 2 tabs starts view did load at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

hello my app is build out of Tab bar controller and the Starting arrow points at the grey windows "Tab Bar Controller", 
I have 2 tabs, 1 and 2 . the thing is I need to load a table from sql from each tab the first time I enter it, since the default screen when I enter the screen is "1" it loads perfectly, when I switch to tab "2" the table loads empty.
now if I change the arrow to start from either the "1" or "2" individually then the table loads fine, therefor I suspect somethings is not right with viewdidload.
asking your help

(I tried to use print func in both ViewDidLoad to see if they start together , and no each print came when I clicked the tab I wanted)

Comment: When do you load the contents of view controllers? In viewDidLoad? Also, try to use breakpoints to check if the loading code gets executed.

Comment: the code gets executed yet the table is empty, only when the arrow points on a single view controller it loads perfectly, I execute a query in ViewDidLoad in each controller. (total of 2 different viewdidload's)

Comment: Try reloading the table views in `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reload table views in `viewWillAppear`

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: when I use the func wont it be unwise to load every time I click the tab? is that ok to use since it loads data every time

Comment: You loaded data from the database in `viewDidLoad`. In `viewWillAppear` you only tell the UI to refresh. This should not be a problem and it is a common technique.